# Callback after ForEach (with async function inside) is done

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, foreach, callback, synchronization

I have a .forEach loop with a async function inside of it and my code is executing my callback() before the loop is finished.
Is there a way to make it so it will finish the loop and then move on to my callback().
Here is my code:

```
var transactions = [];
t.transactions.forEach(function(id){
    client.query('SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE id = $1;', [id], function(err, result) {
        if(!err){
            transactions.push({from : result.rows[0].from, to : result.rows[0].to, amount : result.rows[0].amount, time : result.rows[0].ct, message : result.rows[0].message, id : result.rows[0].id});
        }
    });
});
callback(transactions);
return done();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the index parameter of [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to test if you're on the last transaction:

```
var transactions = [];
t.transactions.forEach(function(id, idx){
    client.query('SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE id = $1;', [id], function(err, result) {
        if(!err){
            transactions.push({from : result.rows[0].from, to : result.rows[0].to, amount : result.rows[0].amount, time : result.rows[0].ct, message : result.rows[0].message, id : result.rows[0].id});
        }
        // If this is the last transaction, do the callback
        if(idx === t.transactions.length - 1) callback(transactions);
    });
});
```

Since you've only got one query per transaction, you can put the test inside the query's callback.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Sorry for a late reply I was off the grid for 2 days.